# SQLite Import CSV File - Expected 3 columns, found 1948

Tags: sqlite, csv

I'm trying to import a CSV file (a Pokemon CSV file found at https://github.com/veekun/pokedex/blob/master/pokedex/data/csv/pokemon_species_names.csv ) into SQLite3. I've created a table using the following line:

`sqlite> create table pokemon_species_names (pid integer, lang integer, pokemonName text, genus text);`

Which works fine, of course, but when I try to import the above CSV file, I get the following error:

`sqlite> .separator ","` (EDIT: forgot to add this initially, but I did run this also)

`sqlite> .import ./pokemon_species_names.csv pokemon_species_names`

`Error: ./pokemon_species_names.csv line 1: expected 4 columns of data but found 1948`

Why would it be finding 1948 columns of data when there are only 4?

Comment: I would suspect an end-of-line incompatibility in that csv file. What OS are you running this on?

Comment: What does the file look like on your system?  You may have a newline character issue (eg, you downloaded a file with Unix newlines to a Windows system, and the OS sees it as a single line).

Comment: OS X. I had files from the same source that worked fine, but I also had to modify this particular one to exclude certain data. I did so in Excel.

Comment: @rar Have you tried with the unmodified file?

Comment: Huh. Well what do you know, it worked! Why might that have broken it?

Comment: @rar I'd still suspect line endings, but I'm not familiar enough with MacOS to suggest any troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking at this (5 years later), in TextWrangler on Mac, you select "Save As" Unicode(UTF-8) and Unix(LF).  Then .import will work like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

SQLite may not be looking for the right separator. Try running:

```
.separator ","
```

before the import.

Comment: Ah sorry, I should've specified that I did do this. I'll add it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Turns out the file I was using had problems because I modified it (in Excel). I used the original, unmodified file, and it worked. Thanks to glibdud and Larry Lustig for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your csv file should be coded in Unicode(UTF-8) Unix(LF)
You can do this from TextWrangler

If you saved it from windows/mac it is either Windows(CRLF) or Classic Mac(LF)